# Using a Rotor Cabinet plugin on the Stereo Out channel outputs no sound when panning the input track hard right

Tags: logic-pro

I want to use a Logic Pro Rotor Cabinet plugin on an Aux or Master track but this breaks panning from the individual track channels. Channels that are panned hard right output nothing and channels that are panned hard left output 100%. Seems like a stereo / mono problem but I've tried everything I can think of. The same doesn't occur on any other plugins.

Logic Version: 10.7.5
MacOS Version: 12.4

[image]

Comment: Maybe the plugin only takes input from the left channel, mono in. Isn't that how rotator cabinets work anyway? It's like a guitar amp, 1 mono input. If you want stereo in, stereo out, use 2 instances of the rotator simulator plugin. One rotator for the left side and another for the right side of your stereo input. Both halves of the input going to the left input of the respective plugin.

Comment: idk Logic well enough [I'm mainly Cubase], but it does seem odd that it acts like an M/S plugin, or even a stereo plugin accidentally inserted on a mono track [especially as it only has a stereo version; if you switch a track to mono, it is not offered as an option] It would be good to know what version Logic, what OS & if anyone else can repro on a different version.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. My goal was to have 1 Aux track with a Rotor plugin shared by multiple tracks all with post pan sends. This was to avoid having to copy the rotor plugin to each track individually and coordinate rotor configuration changes across the tracks. From what I understand of the suggestions here, that seems impossible.

Answer (score 1):

I've confirmed this behavior in Logic Pro 10.7.2, build 5556, sound library 2422.

I searched through the Apple documentation and read the complete section on the Rotor Cabinet effect and did not find anything that confirms this is how it is supposed to work, but I strongly suspect it's by design.

A real Leslie cabinet would have a mono input, so it would make sense for the plugin to have a mono input. What makes less sense is that the plugin does not sum to mono and instead only uses one channel.

It seems it is not possible to use this plugin without destroying the stereo image that exists before the plugin and creating a new stereo image with the plugin. If you want to sum to mono first so that the sound from both the right and left channels are used for the plugin, you can put a Gain plugin (under the Utility section) prior to the Rotor Cabinet and turn on the mono switch in the gain plugin (leave everything else as is).

If you want to preserve the stereo image that exists before the Rotor Cabinet, then I think your only good option is to use two aux sends with Rotor Cabinet on both. One aux send gets the left channel information sent to it, and the other gets the right channel information sent to it. Then you could adjust the balance controls on the auxes to have some residual amount of right/left as they go to the main mix.

Comment: Thanks. The pan would still need to be controlled from the Aux channel in this configuration unless I am misunderstanding your suggestion? I need to control the pan from the individual tracks themselves using the Post Pan option, otherwise I'll just have to use the Rotor directly on the track itself and copy the plugin across the required tracks.

Comment: It does kind of make sense for it to be mono in/stereo out, as that's what a real Leslie is. The arbitrary 'right only' makes little sense, though. The unfortunate thing about setting up two rotors is that you won't be able to sync them, you'll in effect have two Leslie cabs. The other thing about Leslie cabs is they *always* used to be panned as mono, even if 2 mics were used. Your classic 60s/70s Leslie has no spread. idk Logic's Rotor specifically, but I used to always narrow any Hammond/Leslie effect to sound 'more authentic'.